# JSoup extracting data from within paragraph

Tags: java, jsoup, paragraph

I want to extract  all the text there is between all paragraphs on an unknown site (meaning i do not know the structure of the site).

So far i've got:

```
        Elements paragraphEmail = doc.select("p");
```

Where `doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();`

```
        for (Element e : paragraphEmail) {

            }
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: And why doesn't that work for you? Just iterate over each element with a loop and you have all the text.

Comment: @Zyril what am i suppose to do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`doc.select("p")` will give you all the paragraph elements as a collection `Elements`.

Use a for each loop to get the text:

```
for(Element e : paragraphEmail){
    System.out.println(e.text());
}
```

I suggest you take a look at the Jsoup cookbook and the API reference to get more familiar with the methods in Jsoup.

[Cookbook](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/)
[API Reference](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/)